# Проверка значения на "старость"

Tags: javascript, java, c#

Есть переменная. Она в бесконечном цикле выдаёт значения типа:

```
1 - 1-й шаг
1 - 2-й шаг
1 - 3-й шаг
1 - 4-й шаг
```

Эти значения могут изменяться. То есть:

```
2  - 1-й шаг
1  - 2-й шаг
4  - 3-й шаг
10 - 4-й шаг
```

Нужно сделать так, чтобы при повторяющемся значении результат выводился только 1 раз. То есть:

Значения:

```
1
1
1
1
```

Результат:

```
1
```

Но! Суть в том, что эти значения могут идти ещё и так:

```
2
1
2
1
2
1
2
```

Получается, нужно сделать проверку старой переменной на ещё одну переменную, которая шла перед старой...

То есть вариант проверки типа

```
int i = 0;
int variable = 10;
if (i != variable) {
    i = variable;
    //Do something...
}
```

откладывается, ибо значение там постоянно меняется.

Вот то, что у меня есть на данный момент:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 32; i++)
{
    float x = vam.ReadFloat((IntPtr)0xC7DD58 + 48 + 160 * i);
    float y = vam.ReadFloat((IntPtr)0xC7DD58 + 52 + 160 * i);
    float z = vam.ReadFloat((IntPtr)0xC7DD58 + 56 + 160 * i);

    float nx = 0;
    float ny = 0;
    float nz = 0;

    if (x > 0f && x < 60f && y < 0f && z>0f && z < 392f)
    {
        nx = x;
        ny = y;
        nz = z;
    }
    if (ny < -216 && ny > -350 && nx > 4 && nx < 60 && nz > 350 && nz < 391)
    {
        if (ny != old_y && nx != old_x)
        {
            old_z = nz;
            old_y = ny;
            old_x = nx;

            Console.WriteLine("======================= NORMALIZE ==========================");
            Console.WriteLine(nx);
            Console.WriteLine(ny);
            Console.WriteLine(nz);
            Console.WriteLine("=======================================================");
        }
    }
    else
    {
    }
}
```

Что этот код выдаёт:

```
======================= NORMALIZE ==========================
14.18555
-286.5293
390.2
=======================================================
======================= NORMALIZE ==========================
50.3623
-223.5
390.2
=======================================================
======================= NORMALIZE ==========================
14.18555
-286.5293
390.2
=======================================================
======================= NORMALIZE ==========================
50.3623
-223.5
390.2
=======================================================
======================= NORMALIZE ==========================
14.18555
-286.5293
390.2
=======================================================
======================= NORMALIZE ==========================
50.3623
-223.5
390.2
=======================================================
======================= NORMALIZE ==========================
14.18555
-286.5293
390.2
=======================================================
======================= NORMALIZE ==========================
50.3623
-223.5
390.2
=======================================================
======================= NORMALIZE ==========================
14.18555
-286.5293
390.2
=======================================================
======================= NORMALIZE ==========================
50.3623
-223.5
390.2
=======================================================
======================= NORMALIZE ==========================
14.18555
-286.5293
390.2
=======================================================
======================= NORMALIZE ==========================
50.3623
-223.5
390.2
=======================================================
======================= NORMALIZE ==========================
14.18555
-286.5293
390.2
=======================================================
======================= NORMALIZE ==========================
50.3623
-223.5
390.2
=======================================================
======================= NORMALIZE ==========================
14.18555
-286.5293
390.2
=======================================================
======================= NORMALIZE ==========================
50.3623
-223.5
390.2
=======================================================
======================= NORMALIZE ==========================
14.18555
-286.5293
390.2
=======================================================
======================= NORMALIZE ==========================
50.3623
-223.5
390.2
=======================================================
======================= NORMALIZE ==========================
14.18555
-286.5293
390.2
=======================================================
======================= NORMALIZE ==========================
50.3623
-223.5
390.2
=======================================================
======================= NORMALIZE ==========================
14.18555
-286.5293
390.2
=======================================================
======================= NORMALIZE ==========================
50.3623
-223.5
390.2
=======================================================
======================= NORMALIZE ==========================
14.18555
-286.5293
390.2
=======================================================
======================= NORMALIZE ==========================
50.3623
-223.5
390.2
=======================================================
======================= NORMALIZE ==========================
14.18555
-286.5293
390.2
=======================================================
======================= NORMALIZE ==========================
50.3623
-223.5
390.2
=======================================================
======================= NORMALIZE ==========================
14.18555
-286.5293
390.2
=======================================================
======================= NORMALIZE ==========================
50.3623
-223.5
390.2
=======================================================
======================= NORMALIZE ==========================
14.18555
-286.5293
390.2
=======================================================
======================= NORMALIZE ==========================
50.3623
-223.5
390.2
=======================================================
```

Что он должен выдавать:

```
======================= NORMALIZE ==========================
14.18555
-286.5293
390.2
=======================================================
======================= NORMALIZE ==========================
50.3623
-223.5
390.2
=======================================================
```

Comment: "Надеюсь, объяснил понятно," - нет, не надейтесь :).

Comment: То есть для последовательности `1 2 1 4 1 1 2 3` должно вывести `1 2 4 3`? Если значение уже было когда-либо, то его не выводить?

Comment: @Igor, Подправил чутка, может что-то проясниться, просто я сам вообще не могу придумать :c

Comment: @Regent, обновите страницу, я там дописал кое-что. Но в общем да, вы, похоже, меня поняли :)

Comment: @user300058 можно хранить значения, которые уже были "использованы", в массиве, списке или `Set`-е и перед выводом сверяться.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для хранения всех старых значений и проверки значения на "старость" можно использовать, например, массив, `List` или `Set`.

Пример на Java с использованием `HashSet`:

```
HashSet<Double> usedValues = new HashSet<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    double value = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
    if (!usedValues.contains(value))
    {
        System.out.println("New value: " + value);
        usedValues.add(value);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Old value: " + value);
    }
}
```

Пример вывода:

> New value: 2.0
>   Old value: 2.0
>   New value: 0.0
>   Old value: 2.0
>   New value: 3.0
>   New value: 4.0
>   Old value: 3.0
>   Old value: 3.0
>   Old value: 4.0
>   Old value: 4.0

Comment: `HashSet<Double>` - а java хорошо работает с точностью для double? У них там нет такого, что одно число может быть чуууть меньше 2, другое чууууть больше?

Comment: @tym32167 и при этом эти два числа равны? Внутри класса `Double`, судя по исходникам из JDK, `equals` происходит с помощью преобразования обоих чисел к long` с последующим их сравнением. Так что если биты в двух double числах разные, то они должны считать разными.

Comment: Ну, насколько я помню, в дотнете 2 одинаково посчитанных double могут быть не равны из за этой погрешности в точности

Comment: @tym32167 подсчитанные с точностью большей, чем у double, могут быть не равны - это верно, но здесь вопрос не в этом. В исходной задаче уже есть набор чисел с точностью заведомо меньше, чем позволяет хранить double, так что их сравнение будет идти без проблем.